# Plot/Draw Circle in WindowsForms Chart

Tags: c#, winforms, plot, charts, draw

Is there any possibility to plot a circle in a `WindowsForm Chart`?

A method-call as follows would be really nice!

```
Graph.Series["circle"].Circle.Add(centerX, centerY, radius);
```

[image: w]

Comment: There are two basic choices: You can use the Paintxxx event to draw like you can do on any control. Or you can use chart elements. either a curved series or a suitable Annotaton. For the 1st pton you calculate thebounding rectangle and call DrawEllipse. For the latter you need to determine the points of a circular bezier. This sounds harder than it is; you can create a Graphics path and AddEllipse. Then those points are in the PathPoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I created myself a work around.
Maybe it helps someone

```
public void DrawCircle(Chart Graph, double centerX, double centerY, double radius, int amountOfEdges)
{
    string name = "circle_" + centerX + centerY + radius + amountOfEdges;

    // Create new data series
    if (Graph.Series.IndexOf(name) == -1)
        Graph.Series.Add(name);

    // preferences of the line
    Graph.Series[name].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
    Graph.Series[name].Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
    Graph.Series[name].BorderWidth = 1;
    Graph.Series[name].IsVisibleInLegend = false;

    // add line segments (first one also as last one)
    for (int k = 0; k <= amountOfEdges; k++)
    {
        double x = centerX + radius * Math.Cos(k * 2 * Math.PI / amountOfEdges);
        double y = centerY + radius * Math.Sin(k * 2 * Math.PI / amountOfEdges);
        Graph.Series[name].Points.AddXY(x, y);
    }
}
```

You can call it for example via

```
DrawCircle(Graph, 5, 4, 3, 30);
```

Around 30 points should be enough to get a nice circle instead of a polygon, but depends on the size of your chart.

Comment: Choosing type spline will let you do with (a lot) less points.